# Uso de except em uma expressão lambda

Tags: c#

Tenho essa expressão e não funciona:

```
var busca = listaCommiter.Where(l => l.Except(listaFarm.ToString()));
```

Já removi o ToString() e mesmo assim nada.
`listaCommiter` e `listaFarm` são duas listas de string. Eu tentei com `Contains` e mesmo os arquivos existindo em ambas as listas ele diz que são diferentes. Uma lista eu preencho com GetFileName e a outra eu Splito um arquivo txt e monto a lista. Acho que a lista do txt, deve ter caracteres estranhos e por isso a diferença, removi os `\n` e também os `\r`, mas pode ter algo mais. Bem, como eu comparo as duas listas com lambda?

Comment: Qual a sua intenção? Criar uma nova lista com todos os dados da segunda que não existem na primeira? (Isso foi uma suposição)

Comment: @jbueno, exatamente isso. Preciso criar uma lista e depois deletar do arquivo os nomes que estão na lista Commiter e não estão na lista Farm.

Comment: Eu fiz assim e funcionou: `var busca = listaCommiter.Except(listaFarm);`. Só não consegui fazer com lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não consigo entender porquê você utilizou o `Where`, você não precisa dele. Só é necessário usar o [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) para ter o resultado esperado.

A documentação do método `Except` diz:

> Produz a diferença de duas sequências usando o comparador de igualdade padrão para comparar valores.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var lista = new [] {"nome", "teste", "texto", "outro"};    
var lista2 = new [] {"nome", "teste", "texto", "outro2"};

var excecoes = lista2.Except(lista).ToList();

excecoes.ForEach(WriteLine);
```

A saída será `outro2`.

Veja no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1VXH4z)